# Build a release ready apk for cocos2d-x project using commands

Tags: javascript, command-line, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I have a cocos2d-x (v 3.14) javascript project which is running fine in browser. I am using webstorm to write code. Now I want to export my project to android, ios, windows desktop and MAC using command line. Please help me with the commands for each.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as easy as you might think. Every device is different and you may need to edit your code to work with some platforms.

Starting with android, you should refer to the [docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/installation/Android-terminal/index.html)

iOS and Mac requires you to have a Mac, as well as XCode and a Developer license. Just have a look at the [cocos2d docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/installation/iOS/index.html) to prepare everything.

Same with windows, look at the docs.

After preparing you cann build in command line by using the command:

```
cocos deploy <platform>
```

with platform be the target platform. But I need to warn you your build will not work the first time you try it, every system works in another way and need modification in your cocos-code.

Hope I could help you.